# Preallocate number of non-zeroes in ojAlgo

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, ojalgo

Since filling a huge SparseStore matrix from the ojAlgo package is the bottleneck of my program, I wanted to ask if there is a method or way to preallocate the number of nonzero elements like Matlab's 'spalloc' method. This would drastically reduce the runtime of my program. I appreciate any help!

Comment: The underlying SparseArray class has this feature, but unfortunately it's not accessible via SparseStore. It really should be possible to control this. If you open an issue at GitHub I'll find a way to implement it.

Comment: Just opened one, thank you!